# Is URI size included in HTTP_MAX_HEADER_SIZE limit in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, rest, http, header, http-headers

I'm getting `HPE_HEADER_OVERFLOW` error on http request in nodejs with 8347 bytes parsed. I know that nodejs `HTTP_MAX_HEADER_SIZE` is 8192 bytes.

The http request buffer is composed by URI declaration (e.g. GET /path HTTP/2) and headers keys and values.
Removing URI declaration the buffer size containing headers only is 6153 bytes.

Is URI size included in `HTTP_MAX_HEADER_SIZE` limit in nodejs (I suppose so)? 
Is this documented somewhere?